# Highlight the name of the month with the highest record in

Tags: excel

I m trying to Highlight the name of the month with the highest record in , which is Jan-08 using conditional formatting but its not working.

My data is in this form:
[image: My data is in this form]

Comment: Are you using a formula in your conditional formatting? What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried with index match formula but its not working also i have tried max formula but its only working with rows not with column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula as:

```
=B$3=MAX($B$3:$M$3)
```

Don't forget to add the `$` sign.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this using conditional formatting follow the following steps:

1. Select range `B2:M2`
2. On the **Home** menu tab, Click on **Conditional Formatting** under the **Styles** group. From the drop-down menu, choose **Manage Rules…**

[image]

3. In the **Conditional Formatting Rules Manager** click on **New Rule…**

[image]

4. Choose **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and click **Format…** to set up how your want your highlight to look. Enter the formula as `=B3=MAX("$B$3:$M$3")` and click `OK`

[image]

5. Click **Apply** and **OK**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in excel go to conditional formatting > Manage Rules... > Format only cells that contain

> Here in edit the rule description section , apply MAX() function logic to your cells , and also you can define the formatting in which the cell should look .

Comment: Thank you for your response
actually i want to highlight month column with the highest record not record column

Comment: I have tried so many times but it's highlighting entire column

Comment: i know that is not working, i'm just trying something else, will reply if come up with something .

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional formatting

Select the data that you want to conditionally format

On the ***Home tab***, in the ***Styles group***, click on ***Conditional Formatting***, and then click  ***Highlight cells rules*** then ***Greater Then...***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response
actually i want to highlight month column with the highest record not record column

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the dates B2:M2 then go to Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Use a formula and put in:-

```
=B3=MAX($B$3:$M$3)
```

then choose the format you want to use.

[image]